# Problema - Identificador no válido

Tags: sql, oracle

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema al insertar datos mediante objetos me dice que el identificador no es válido y no se que pueda ser. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

create or replace type aerolineas as object
(   
    cod_aerol number(6),
    nom_aerol char(20)
);
/

create or replace type ciudades as object
(
    cod_ciudad number(4),
    nom_ciudad char(20),
    pais char(20)
);
/

create or replace type pasajeros as object
(
    cod_pasajero number(11),
    nombre varchar(30),
    apellido varchar(30),
    edad number(3),
    ciudad number(4),
    telefono char(15),
    direccion varchar(25)
);
/

create table vuelos1(
    cod_vuelo number(8) not null,
    capacidad number(3) not null,
    h_inicio date not null,
    h_fin date not null,
    origen ciudades,
    destino ciudades,
    escalas number(1) not null,
    aerolinea1 aerolineas,
    constraint pk_vuelos1 primary key(cod_vuelo)
);

create table tickets1(
    cod_ticket number(8) not null,
    cod_vuelo number(8) not null,
    pasajero pasajeros,
    precio number(15) not null,
    constraint pk_tickets1 primary key(cod_ticket),
    constraint fk_tickets1_vuelos1 foreign key(cod_vuelo) references vuelos1(cod_vuelo)
);

insert into vuelos1 values('00000001', '90', '13-06-2017 20:19:00', '14-06-2017 06:10:00',
    origen('0003', 'Madrid', 'España'),
    destino('0004', 'Paris', 'Francia'),'2',
    aerolinea1('000004', 'Air France'));
```

Comment: el objeto `aerolinea1` al parecer no existe en tu base de datos

Comment: Buenas, aerolinea1 es el campo y aerolineas es el objeto, como muestra la captura el objeto aerolineas existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un fallo de concepto, necesitas insertarlo a través de un bloque [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjplsql.htm#ADOBJ070):

```
DECLARE
  origen ciudades;
  destino ciudades;
  aerolinea1 aerolineas;
BEGIN
    origen := ciudades('0003', 'Madrid', 'España');
    destino := ciudades('0004', 'Paris', 'Francia');
    aerolinea1 := aerolineas('000004', 'Air France');
    INSERT INTO vuelos1 VALUES('00000001',
                               '90',
                               '13-06-2017 20:19:00',
                               '14-06-2017 06:10:00',
                               origen,
                               destino,
                               '2', 
                               aerolinea1);
END;
/
```

O si quieres hacerlo directamente (no te lo recomiendo):

```
INSERT INTO vuelos1 VALUES('00000001',
                               '90',
                               '13-06-2017 20:19:00',
                               '14-06-2017 06:10:00',
                               ciudades('0003', 'Madrid', 'España'),
                               ciudades('0004', 'Paris', 'Francia'),
                               '2', 
                               aerolineas('000004', 'Air France'));
```

**PD**: Oracle ofrece [esta](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html) herramienta online ideal para esta clase de *testeos*.

**PD2**: La seleccion de estos campos complejos requiere el uso de [TREAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions206.htm#SQLRF06148). Ejemplo:

```
SELECT TREAT(origen AS ciudades).nom_ciudad FROM vuelos1
```

Comment: Me sirvió ambas opciones, me quedo con la última por que no he visto PL/SQL pero sin embargo por que no me recomiendas la última ? Gracias.

Comment: De nada .. la razón es que el PL/SQL permite un código mucho mas programático , o sea estructuras de de control, captura de errores, etc, etc.

Comment: Gracias y respeto a la página que me recomiendas, me da problemas al consultar un query que contenga objetos. [unsupported data type]

Comment: Yo he testeado tu caso en esa web, tiene una sección para crear el DDL (tablas, objetos, etc) y otra para el DML donde iría la insert

Comment: Observe mi captura por favor [ http://prntscr.com/flpau3 ]

Comment: Necesitas usar `TREAT` te he puesto un ejemplo en la respuesta

Comment: Eso es lo que se llamaría una instancia ?, pero si quiero ver la información completa de un vuelo junto a sus objetos en una consulta como haría, como aplicaría ese treat. ?

Comment: Tengo entendido que es instanciar, me corrige si estoy mal por favor.

Comment: Si necesitas las tres propiedades del objeto origen, tendrás que usar tres veces `TREAT`,  lo mas fácil es equipararlas concolumnas

Answer (score 2):

`aerolinea1` no es un objeto declarado dentro de tu base de datos, `aerolinea1` es el nombre de tu columna.

El objeto declarado es el siguiente:

```
create or replace type aerolineas as object
(   
   cod_aerol number(6),
   nom_aerol char(20)
);
```

Debería insertar aplicando lo siguiente:

```
insert into vuelos1 values('00000001', '90', '13-06-2017 20:19:00', '14-06-
2017 06:10:00',
origen('0003', 'Madrid', 'España'),
destino('0004', 'Paris', 'Francia'),'2',
aerolineas('000004', 'Air France'));
```

llamando al objeto dentro de la inserción, no a la columna

```
aerolineas('000004', 'Air France')
```

Comment: Da el mismo error, se supone que se hace referencia al nombre de la columna después de que arriba esté bien definido el objeto, de esa forma me habían explicado.

Comment: Ahora corregí la publicación, el nombre del objeto en mi ejemplo no estaba bien definido.

Comment: Si y estaba equivocado, se hace referencia es al nombre de objeto no a la columna.

Comment: Que bien, me alegro. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu ayuda.

Comment: Para eso estamos  :)